# Why is @property slower that an attribute while bytecode is the same

Tags: python, performance, properties, cpython, python-internals

Consider this chunk of code:

```py
import timeit
import dis

class Bob(object):
    __slots__ = "_a",

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = "a"

    @property
    def a_prop(self):
        return self._a

bob = Bob()

def return_attribute():
    return bob._a

def return_property():
    return bob.a_prop

print(dis.dis(return_attribute))
print(dis.dis(return_property))

print("attribute:")
print(timeit.timeit("return_attribute()",
                    setup="from __main__ import return_attribute", number=1000000))
print("@property:")
print(timeit.timeit("return_property()",
                    setup="from __main__ import return_property", number=1000000))
```

It is easy to see that `return_attribute` and `return_property` result in the same byte code:

```
 17           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bob)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (_a)
              6 RETURN_VALUE        
None
 20           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bob)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (a_prop)
              6 RETURN_VALUE        
None
```

However, timings are different:

```py
attribute:
0.106526851654
@property:
0.210631132126
```

Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A property is executed as a *function call*, while the attribute lookup is merely a hash table (dictionary) lookup. So yes, that'll always be slower.

The `LOAD_ATTR` bytecode is not a fixed-time operation here. What you are missing is that `LOAD_ATTR` *delegates attribute lookups to the object type*; by triggering C code that:

- Finds the type of the object on the top of the stack, and asks it to produce the value for the attribute, given the instance. See the [`ceval.c` evaluation loop section for `LOAD_ATTR`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/134f79682d6729e3cf84b665d615f576075550e8/Python/ceval.c#L2570-L2579), which invokes [`PyObject_GetAttr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr). For custom Python classes this ends up calling the [`_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/134f79682d6729e3cf84b665d615f576075550e8/Objects/object.c#L1196-L1301) (via the [`type->tp_getattro` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) and [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GenericGetAttr).
- The object then looks through its own MRO for any *descriptor objects* that match the attribute name. If there is such an object, and it is a data descriptor, search stops and the data descriptor is bound ([`descriptor.__get__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) is called on it) and the result returned. See [these lines is `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/134f79682d6729e3cf84b665d615f576075550e8/Objects/object.c#L1228-L1242).
- If there are no data descriptors, looks at the instance `__dict__` for the attribute name as a key. If such a key exists, the corresponding value is returned; see [these lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/134f79682d6729e3cf84b665d615f576075550e8/Objects/object.c#L1244-L1275).
- If there is no such key in the instance `__dict__`, but there was a non-data descriptor found, then that descriptor is bound (`__get__` is called on it), and the result is returned, in [this section](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/134f79682d6729e3cf84b665d615f576075550e8/Objects/object.c#L1277-L1290).
- If there is a `__getattr__` method defined on the class, call that method. See [these lines in `slot_tp_getattr_hook`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/134f79682d6729e3cf84b665d615f576075550e8/Objects/typeobject.c#L6483-L6486), which is installed when you add a `__getattr__` hook to a class.
- otherwise, raise `AttributeError`.

A `property` object is a data descriptor; it implements not only `__get__` but also the `__set__` and `__delete__` methods. Calling `__get__` on the `property` with an instance causes the `property` object to call the registered getter function.

See the [*Descriptor HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for more information on descriptors, as well as the [*Invoking Descriptors* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) of the Python datamodel documentation.

The bytecode *doesn't differ* because it is not up to the `LOAD_ATTR` bytecode to decide if the attribute is a property or a regular attribute. Python is a dynamic language, and the compiler *can't know up front* if the attribute accessed is going to be a property. You can alter your class *at any time*:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 42

f = Foo()
print(f.bar)  # 42

Foo.bar = property(lambda self: 81)
print(f.bar)  # 81
```

In the above example, while you start with the `bar` name only existing as an attribute on the `f` instance of class `Foo`, by adding the `Foo.bar` `property` object we intercepted the lookup procedure for the name `bar`, because a `property` is a data descriptor and so gets to override any instance lookups.   **But Python can't know this in advance and so can't provide a different bytecode for property lookups**. The `Foo.bar` assignment could happen in a completely unrelated module, for example.

Comment: "A property is executed as a function call" - I don't see it in the byte code

Comment: @ivaigult: no, and you won't.

Comment: @ivaigult: the byte code is **static**, but attributes are not static.